# If I backup my wordpress blog, how can I back-up all the external images I've embedded?

Tags: wordpress.com-hosting, backup

As in - some of the images I've uploaded - like the ones at http://astroclimatology.wordpress.com/2011/11/02/interesting-dif-between-surface-temperature-and-p850-temperature/ - use images from a webpage that won't be here a year from now - as I'm leaving the school in a year.

Answer (score 1):

if you're not hosting them you can't back them up

Comment: Indeed. If they truly are *external* images, you'll need to download each one manually in order to back them up. And even then, you'll have to associate each image manually if you ever have to restore them.

Answer (score 0):

The **/wp-content/uploads** directory contains them. But read on.

**Backup consists of two elements:**

1. Backup the database contents *(ALL tables including plugin specific customs)*
2. Backup the `/wp-content/` folder completely

The #2 is because some plugins and themes store settings in files, even if totally inadvisable *(that never stopped them)*. And it's best to save everything just to stay on the safe side.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

you get your all external images when you upload your database back 
in Your_Database->wp_posts->post_content you can see your content in html format so its clear that their are anchor tags also so you'll get your external images for sure.